# Django REST Framework how to retrieve Nested relationships

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest framework in my project and I need to retrieve data from my `Author` model and related `Books` model, so the data should look like this:

{

```
    'author': 'SomeAuthor',
    'books': [
        {'title': 'Example1'},
        {'title': 'Example1'},
        {'title': 'Example1'},
        ...
    ],}.
    {
    'author': 'SomeAuthor2',
    'books': [
        {'title': 'Example1'},
        {'title': 'Example1'},
        {'title': 'Example1'},
        ...
    ],
}
```

my here is models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   author = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

as was described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships), my serializer.py looks like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title']

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    book = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['author', 'book']
```

here is my views.py:

```
def author_list_view(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        author_list = Author.objects.all()
        serializer = AuthorSerializer(author_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and i've got this result:

```
[
    {
        "author": SomeAuthor,

    },
    {
        "author": SomeAuthor2,

    }
]
```

without `books`, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might be able to use a method field in your AuthorSerializer class. see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model `Author` doesn't have field `book`. You can simply add `related_name=books` to `Author` model. Then change `book` to `books`, on `AuthorSerializer`. Documentation has great example on how to manage nested serializers. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SerializerMethodField.  Here is a similar example with Cars and Factories.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Factory(models.Model):
   factory = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.factory


class Car(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
   factory = models.ForeignKey('Factory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Car, Factory

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'


class FactorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    cars = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_cars(self, obj):
        return CarSerializer(Car.objects.filter(factory=obj), many=True).data


    class Meta:
        model = Factory
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Car, Factory
from .serializers import CarSerializer, FactorySerializer

# Create your views here.
class CarList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer

class FactoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Factory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FactorySerializer
```

If I go to http://127.0.0.1:7000/vehicles/factories I will get this data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "cars": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Piece Of Junk",
                "factory": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Hybrid Junk",
                "factory": 1
            }
        ],
        "factory": "JunkMaker"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cars": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Piece of Crap",
                "factory": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Electric Piece of Crap",
                "factory": 2
            }
        ],
        "factory": "CrapMaker"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you are using Author model for AuthorSerializer, and trying to take a field 'book' that does not exist in the model.
You should add the field 'books' to Author and make it a OneToManyField that references the Book model.

You may read about OneToManyField here: [OneToManyField](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/many-to-one/)